# How to remove the "max-height" online style of modal?

Tags: html, css, drupal, modal-dialog

I created a code that displays a link to open a modal window.

The problem is that the text comes out of the window.

When I inspect the code of my page, there is an online style `style="max-height: 570px;"`

If I add the following code to my style sheet, it works. But is there another solution? I make a mistake in my code :

```
div#drupal-modal--content[style] {
  max-height: none !important;
}
```

How to remove the online style of modal ?

```
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $store_name = $this->order->getStore()->getName();
    $store_id = $this->order->getStoreId();
    $pane_form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    $attributes = [
      'attributes' => [
        'class' => 'use-ajax',
        'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
        'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
          'width' => auto,
        ]),
      ],
    ];
```

[image]

Comment: I think I would have solved the problem the way you did - seems to me like a very reasonable way to utilise !important.